# Error while trying to reuse weights for RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to reuse the Bidirectional LSTM weights for 2 very similar computations, but I am getting an error and have no idea what I am doing wrong.
I have a class for the basic module :

```
class BasicAttn(object):    
    def __init__(self, keep_prob, value_vec_size):    
        self.rnn_cell_fw = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(value_vec_size/2, reuse=True)
        self.rnn_cell_fw = DropoutWrapper(self.rnn_cell_fw, input_keep_prob=self.keep_prob)
        self.rnn_cell_bw = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(value_vec_size/2, reuse=True)
        self.rnn_cell_bw = DropoutWrapper(self.rnn_cell_bw, input_keep_prob=self.keep_prob)

    def build_graph(self, values, values_mask, keys):
        blended_reps = compute_blended_reps()
        with tf.variable_scope('BasicAttn_BRNN', reuse=True):
        (fw_out, bw_out), _ = 
        tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(self.rnn_cell_fw, self.rnn_cell_bw, blended_reps, dtype=tf.float32, scope='BasicAttn_BRNN')
```

Then, the module gets called while building the graph

```
    attn_layer_start = BasicAttn(...)
    blended_reps_start = attn_layer_start.build_graph(...)
    attn_layer_end = BasicAttn(...)
    blended_reps_end = attn_layer_end.build_graph(...)
```

But I get the error saying that TensorFlow is unable to reuse the RNNs?

```
ValueError: Variable QAModel/BasicAttn_BRNN/BasicAttn_BRNN/fw/lstm_cell/kernel does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope
```

There is a lot of code, so I have trimmed out the parts which I thought were unneccessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reuse=True` means that the variables have been created previously with `reuse=False`, so each `tf.get_variable` (in your case abstracted behind the LSTM interface) expects the variable to already exist.

To have a mode in which variables created if they do not exist yet, and reused otherwise, you need to set `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE` (as the error message suggests).

So replace all occurrences of `reuse=True` with `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE`

Here's the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope